# Combine multiple JSON files, and parse into CSV

Tags: json, csv

I have about 100 JSON files, all titled with different dates and I need to merge them into one CSV file that has headers "date", "real_name", "text".

There are no dates listed in the JSON itself, and the real_name is nested. I haven't worked with JSON in a while and am a little lost.

The basic structure of the JSON looks more or less like this:

Filename: 2021-01-18.json

```
[
    {
        "client_msg_id": "xxxx",
        "type": "message",
        "text": "THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO PULL",
        "user": "XXX",
        "user_profile": {
            "first_name": "XXX",
            "real_name": "THIS IS THE NAME I WANT TO PULL",
            "display_name": "XXX",
            "is_restricted": false,
            "is_ultra_restricted": false
        },
        "blocks": [
            {
                "type": "rich_text",
                "block_id": "yf=A9",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So far I have

```
import glob 
read_files = glob.glob("*.json")
output_list = []
all_items = []

for f in read_files:
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        output_list.append(json.load(infile))
    data = {}
    for obj in output_list[]
        data['date'] = f
        data['text'] = 'text'
        data['real_name'] = 'real_name'
        all_items.append(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've read the JSON object, just index into the dictionaries for the data.  You might need `obj[0]['text']`, etc., if your JSON data is really in a list in each file, but that seems odd and I'm assuming your data was pasted from `output_list` after you'd collected the data.  So assuming your file content is exactly like below:

```json
{
    "client_msg_id": "xxxx",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO PULL",
    "user": "XXX",
    "user_profile": {
        "first_name": "XXX",
        "real_name": "THIS IS THE NAME I WANT TO PULL",
        "display_name": "XXX",
        "is_restricted": false,
        "is_ultra_restricted": false
    },
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "rich_text",
            "block_id": "yf=A9",
        }
    ]
}
```

test.py:

```py
import json
import glob 
from pathlib import Path

read_files = glob.glob("*.json")
output_list = []
all_items = []
for f in read_files:
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        output_list.append(json.load(infile))
    data = {}
    for obj in output_list:
        data['date'] = Path(f).stem
        data['text'] = obj['text']
        data['real_name'] = obj['user_profile']['real_name']
        all_items.append(data)
print(all_items)
```

Output:

```
[{'date': '2021-01-18', 'text': 'THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO PULL', 'real_name': 'THIS IS THE NAME I WANT TO PULL'}]
```